# Best language for data transformation (ETL)

Tags: etl

What is the best end-user language for data transformation (ETL), ideally something that can run in a JVM (with a LGPL like license).

With end-user meaning users who are IT related but might not be experts in OO or like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com). It is Java based ETL tool. You can either define transformation through its visual designer or handcode directly in XML files that are used to store data about transformations.

It also uses its own transformation language - CTL that is used inside transformation components. You do not need to be expert in OOP to use it.

Comment: There is LGPL version of CloverETL Engine - [CloverETL on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloveretl/)

Answer (score -1):

Rust is the best language. In fact, companies can now evolve from ETL to STL or Stream, Transform and Load with a technology like InfinyOn Cloud. InfinyOn Cloud is a fully managed Fluvio service. This solution brief explains how the Financial Services industry is leveraging this tech:
https://www.infinyon.com/resources/real-time-data-trasformation/

Comment: This seems like a opinion based question and answer

Comment: The market share of ETL adoption of Rust in the current market is tiny to nothing. This answer could influence newer developers to data engineering .etc to learn Rust instead of languages like Python & Java which are the main languages used in ETL & data engineering.